# How display a border color to a circle in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how it is possible to set a border color of a circle. My code is :

```
child: Container(
  child: ClipOval(
    child: Container(
      color: colorList[index],
      height: 30.0,
      width: 30.0,
      child: Center(
        child: new Text((index+1).toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

So i use Clipoval for display a circle, i can set color of the circle and text in it without any problem but i need set the color of border of the circle. I want to display white circle with red border on white background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) on your Container to achieve this. You don't need a ClipOval, instead you can apply shape parameter on BoxDecoration to get circular appearance.

```
Container(
   child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.grey,
         border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
         shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      height: 30.0,
      width: 30.0,
      child: Center(
         // Your Widget
      ),
   ),
),
```

Comment: @axis-medias: If it helped, could you please accept the answer ? It encourages me a lot :)

Comment: how i can do it ? I Don't know this website, please help

Comment: @axis-medias : There is a check mark near to my answer you can click that to accept it (near to that up&down arrows). For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks you :) Normally all is good now, i have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is the [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) class. Here is an example:

```
class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.deepOrange;
    paint.strokeWidth = 5;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), 80, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```